# Chrome extension: have an extension listen for an event on a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that im making for my site, currently i have the extension checking the database every minute for updates.

Is it possible to have the extension listen for an event on the actual page?

Something like this

```
this.trigger('sendUpdate', data) //this happened on the page

this.on(sendUpdate, function(){ //this is what the chrome extension listens for
    //do stuff with data
})
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you need to add a *content_script*.

*content_script* have full access to the DOM and you can bind to all events on page

just add this to the menifest file

```
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js":"your injected script.js"
}]
```

[Read the documentation here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts)

Also, from your question, it looks like you going to be working with a custom event so your *content_scrip* js is going to be something similar to this

```
document.addEventListener('yourEventName', function(e){
   //send message to ext
   var someInformation = {/*your msg here*/}
   chrome.extension.sendMessage(someInformation, function(response) {
      //callback
   });
}, false);
```

The background page should listen for a message.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(myMessage, sender, sendResponse){
    //do something that only the extension has privileges here
    return true;
 });
```

Then you can trigger the Event from all scripts on the page...

```
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('yourEventName', true, true);
var some_element = document;
some_element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: do you have an example on how to listen for an event from the content script

Answer (score 0):

Recommended chrome extensions manifest version is now V3 ([V2 should be deprecated in June 2024](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/resuming-the-transition-to-mv3#the_phase-out_timeline)) the `sendMessage` method has moved to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in mv3 api.

See documentation for manifest v3 (MV3): https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

Comment: updated to a more general context ;)