# Call a function in chrome extension from a website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to call a function in the chrome plugin from regular website ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire an event in a regular website and have the context script listen for it.  See this entry: [Chrome extension: have an extension listen for an event on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814841/chrome-extension-have-an-extension-listen-for-an-event-on-a-page)